# How do I call a data frame in R that is titled a number?

Tags: r

I have a bunch of data frames that are titled 100, 102, 104...etc (after performing a split) but I can't seem to call them in R because they are numbers.

When I merge a data frame with these, I have tried putting "" and '' around them, etc. but then it only fills in the column with the number, not the data frame itself.

Any one know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Consider renaming the labels of the column you are splitting on, using for example `paste()`.

Comment: `split` returns a list. Instead of using backticks, you can simply use `thelist[["100"]]`. It is unclear where the described issue would appear after using `split`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can protect identifiers with backticks:

```
R> `123` <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=letters[1:3])
R> `123`
  a b
1 1 a
2 2 b
3 3 c
R>
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.  Feel free to accept (click on tickmark) and/or upvote (click on upward-facing triangle).

Comment: Will do (Stack Overflow is making me wait 12 minutes...)